# What do you do when an irrelvent answer is the only answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, relevance

I asked a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886799/exception-when-trying-to-use-layoutkind-explicit) which is not getting too many views. I did revive [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886799/exception-when-trying-to-use-layoutkind-explicit/5886931#5886931) but it was in fairly broken English and really did not help out to answer my underlying problem. I am concerned that people will now see there is one answer on the question and will not even view my question. Am I right to be worried? Also is there any recourse for me to help keep my question interesting so new people will look at it?

Lastly any recommendations on a better title would be appreciated, however I don't know if this is the place to ask for that.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89735/mark-wrong-answers for some discussion from yesterday on this topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not even a bad answer, it's clearly not an answer at all - flag these as such.

Since the user uses terminology that does relate to your problem though, you did the right thing to ask them to elaborate, but failing that, this content is useless and a flag well spent.

Also, hoping not to disgust anyone but going along with offering a title, this might be a little more tempting:

> *VB.NET / LayoutKind.Explicit: Could not load type 'x' from assembly 'y'*

Some might say the VB.NET part is superfluous given that we have tags, though.